# thmbox with normal font and section numbering

Tags: formatting, numbering, theorems

How can i use  "normal font" for definitions and "italic" for remarks (and similar environments like them) in thmbox environment declaring some commands. Also i need numbering as "section" or "subsection".

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[style=normalfont, thmbox=M, name=Definition]{definition}
\declaretheorem[style=remark, thmbox=M, name=Remark]{remark}
\begin{document}
\section{Trying}
\begin{remark}
This is a remark.
\end{remark}
\begin{definition}
This is a definition. i just need this as normal font.
\end{definition}
in addition, numbering should be in section (or subsection).
\end{document}
```

Comment: See Section *1.3.1 Declaring new theoremstyles* from the doc http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/exptl/thmtools/thmtools.pdf

Comment: The problem is the use of `thmbox=M`. It suppress any other style. Removing it the predefined styles `plain` or `remark` will work with `style=plain`, for example. Also you can define new styles as said on documentation above.

Comment: But i need with M or L framed environment. when i remove "thmbox=M" no line is appeared. How can i have both frame and normal font.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pass the corresponding options to `thmbox`, as this package takes over when boxed theorems are to be defined.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm} % amsthm is important!
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[style=remark]{xyz}

\declaretheorem[
  style=plain,
  thmbox={style=M,bodystyle=\normalfont},
  name=Definition,
  within=section,
]{definition}

\declaretheorem[
  style=remark,
  thmbox={style=M,bodystyle=\normalfont,headstyle=\itshape Remark \upshape\theremark},
  name=Remark,
  within=section,
]{remark}

\begin{document}

\section{Trying}

\begin{remark}
This is a remark.
\end{remark}

\begin{definition}
This is a definition. I just need this as normal font.
\end{definition}

In addition, numbering should be in section (or subsection).

\end{document}
```

[image]

I *have* to say that this result is simply awful. Just my opinion, of course.

Comment: I will try to edit. thanks. but i have one more question about numbering. how can i define the counter like this: Remark 1.1, definition 1.2, definition 1.3, theorem 1.4 etc.

Comment: @mert In the definition of `remark` add `numberlike=definition` and remove `within=section`.